# Laravel Policies - $this->authorize not working

Tags: laravel, policy

Task policy:

```
class TaskPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function canSeeTeam()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

AuthServiceProvider:

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $policies = [
        'App\Models\Task' => 'App\Policies\TaskPolicy',
    ];
```

Task controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, Task $task)
    {      
        $this->authorize('canSeeTeam');
        dd('Authorized!');
    }
```

Instead of getting `Authorized!` I get:

> "message": "This action is unauthorized.",
> "exception": "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException",

I'm logged in, and have access to the team, not it matters because `canSeeTeam` always `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to pass the task object to the authorize method:

```
$this->authorize('canSeeTeam', $task);
```

Comment: Wow, that was it, thanks! But why I needed to pass the task object? It's not required in my policy.

Comment: Without the model, the authorize method does not know which policy is relevant.

Answer (score -1):

Please send me error message or replace this:

```
 public function canSeeTeam()
    {
        return true; => return false;
    }
```

Comment: Changing to false doesn't do a thing, error is in the post, I updated it